# Regex to remove apostrophes and replace spaces with underscores

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string similar to this:

```
Frank's Red Hot
```

And I need a regex to remove the apostrophes and replace the spaces with underscores, so it looks like this:

```
franks_red_hot
```

If it makes it all lowercase, bonus points, but there's already a function for that so its not necessary.

Comment: And you have tried what so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There's More Than One Way to Do It

You can do this in a variety of ways. However, I think coding for intent is often the best way if you don't have other considerations driving the matter. Personally, I'd prefer:

```rb
"Frank's Red Hot".downcase.delete(?').tr ' ', ?_
#=> "franks_red_hot"
```

This avoids bang methods in a method chain, which can return nil in unexpected places, and is also easy to break apart or convert to multiple bang methods if you prefer that style of coding.

### Coding for Interim Values

If you care about the interim values, or need to debug your code, you can always use bang methods on multiple lines. This too will avoid bang methods within a method chain. For example:

```rb
str = %q{Frank's Red Hot}
#=> "Frank's Red Hot"

str.downcase!
#=> "frank's red hot"

str.delete! ?'
#=> "franks red hot"

str.tr! ' ', ?_
#=> "franks_red_hot"
```

This technique is certainly easier to debug, but is obviously a lot more verbose. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need Regexp? This should work as you need:

```
string.downcase.gsub("'", '').gsub(' ', '_')
```

Comment: no im not sure, but this should work well thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

```
"Frank's Red Hot".downcase!.gsub!("'","").gsub!(" ","_")
```

You really should try and read the [Object documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) prior to asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Frank's Red Hot"
p s.tr(' ','_').delete("'").downcase #=>"franks_red_hot"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending what version you are using, you can implement a hash using [`String#gsub`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) for your replacement parameters, while using regular expression to match your substring.

```
str.downcase.gsub(/[' ]/, ' ' => '_')
# => franks_red_hot
```

Using with a block:

```
re = { ' ' => '_' }
x  = str.downcase.gsub /[' ]/ do |match|
   re[match.to_s]
 end
```

Using map:

```
map = { "'" => '', ' ' => '_' }
re  = Regexp.union(map.keys)
x = str.downcase.gsub(re, map)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the double `gsub` calls by using the hash syntax

```
s = "Frank's Red Hot"
s.downcase!.gsub(/[ ']/, ' ' => '_') #=> "franks_red_hot"
```